# "TclError: Unknown Option" whilst trying to generate 3x3 grid for Noughts and Crosses

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am working on a small noughts and crosses game to help me start off with Python but I keep getting the error:  `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-11BUTTON"`, how can I fix this.

This is my code to give the error some context:

```py
import ThreadManager
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.CreateWidgets()

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        ButtonList = []

        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                self[f'{x+1}{y+1}BUTTON'] = tk.Button(self, text=f'{x+1}{y+1}_BUTTON')
                self[f'{x+1}{y+1}BUTTON'].grid(row=x+1,column=y+1)

        self.RestartApp = tk.Button(self, text="RESTART", fg="green",
                              command=self.restart)
        self.RestartApp.grid(row=4,column=1)
        self.QuitApp = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.QuitApp.grid(row=4,column=3)

    def Restart():
        print('Restarting')
        # Start game stuff goes here, I haven't gotten onto this part yet as I've only just started it

Window = tk.Tk()
App = Application(master=Window)
App.mainloop()
```

Is there anyway I can fix this? I haven't added any game functions yet and `ThreadManager` is another file which handles some other stuff.

**Stuff tried:**

> Setting the value to `None` before setting it as a button.

Comment: What is the `self[f'{x+1}{y+1}BUTTON']` supposed to do? Why not just use `button = tk.Button(...)`, `button.grid(...)` and then `ButtonList.append(button)`?

Comment: `self[...] = X`, on a widget subclass, is a shorthand for calling `.config()`.  The names you can configure are defined by the widget, you cannot create names of your own.  Dynamically generating names is generally not a good idea anyway, you should just add your Buttons to a list or dict (looks like `ButtonList` was intended for that purpose).

Comment: Also I have no idea what `ThreadManager` is, but be very careful when using threads with `tkinter`. It is possible to crash python if you use `tkinter` in other threads

Comment: @TheLizzard, it adds the button to the class. I'm new to using Python so I'm not sure if it's the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class inherits from `tk.Frame`, it inherits all of the behavior of a frame widget. Part of that behavior is the fact that `self[x]` is just a convenient alias for the `x` attribute (eg: `self['width'] = 100` and `self.configure(width=100)` are synonymous).

The error is telling you that `11BUTTON` is not a valid attribute. It's the same error you get if you do `self.configure('11BUTTON') = ...`

You can't do that with `self[...]`. Instead, you need to create an instance attribute.

For example:

```
self.buttons = {}
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        self.buttons[f'{x+1}{y+1}BUTTON'] = tk.Button(self, text=f'{x+1}{y+1}_BUTTON')
        ...
```

Though, the code would at least arguably be a bit easier to understand if you used a tuple rather than a formatted string:

```
self.buttons[(x,y)] = tk.Button(...)
```

Comment: Thank you for telling and explaing how I should fix the problem (and how I should generate buttons in the future)! It's really helped with my project.